# Edit Product Meta Data after adding to cart, Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to wordpress and woocommerce, I need to edit few Product Meta Data of a product after it has been added to cart. I've used "[WooCommerce Product Gift Wrap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-gift-wrap/)". I need to add a option to allow users to remove gift wrap (If they had selected from product page) and update the product pricing as well.

I tried to change value with `$values['gift_wrap'] = "0";`, but when I print the meta array again, I cannot change the actual data which woocommerce takes from session (or something else). Kindly check the attached [image link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cc0ijy347efxoln/screenshot-localhost%202015-04-28%2010-16-09.png?dl=0) for better understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: Some tried code would be handy to help you

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I haven't done much with the coding, I just changed the value of gift wrap from '1' to '0' (from 'true' to 'false'), but when I display the cart again using '$woocommerce->cart->get_cart()' it's same again (gift_wrap is '1' again). How do I change the value in '$woocommerce->cart->get_cart()' ?